# C# WMI Unparsable query

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

My goal:

- Start a process(Install application) on a remote machine with params
- Wait for the process to finish and throw an event when it's completed.

I'm getting an error "**Unparseable query**" at this line:
var watcher = manWatch.WaitForNextEvent();

I have a database of about 2xx different applications i can install from using this method. Not every application gives me this error during install. Some are succesful and some not. I do believe it's the way I'm going about getting the event. Any ideas?

```
    private void StartAppAction(string PCName, string Command)
    {

        string Params = @"\\" + PCName + @"\C$\SoftwareInstall\" + Command;
        ConnectionOptions conOpt = new ConnectionOptions();
        conOpt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        conOpt.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
        conOpt.EnablePrivileges = true;

        ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", PCName), conOpt);
        manScope.Connect();

        ObjectGetOptions objGetOpt = new ObjectGetOptions();
        ManagementPath manPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
        ManagementClass manClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, manPath, objGetOpt);

        ManagementBaseObject inParams = manClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        inParams["CommandLine"] = Params;
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = manClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

        string queryString = "SELECT * From WIN32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessID= outParams['ProcessID']";
        WqlEventQuery wqlQuery = new WqlEventQuery(queryString);
        ManagementEventWatcher manWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(@"\\" + PCName + @"\root\CIMV2", "SELECT * From WIN32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessID=" + outParams["ProcessID"]);

        var watcher = manWatch.WaitForNextEvent();

        if (watcher["ExitStatus"].ToString() == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Remote Exection Finished Succesfully with ExitCode 0");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Remote Exection exited with the code of " + watcher["ExitStatus"].ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in your WQL sentece
replace this line

```
string queryString = "SELECT * From WIN32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessID= outParams['ProcessID']";
```

by this one

```
string queryString = String.Format("SELECT * From WIN32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessID={0}",outParams['ProcessID']);
```

Comment: Thanks @RRUZ for the reply. Just replaced my code with yours, and I'm still getting the same problem. I also had to add double quotes in the outParams["ProcessID"] part.